# populate listview with custom cursoradapter from sqlite

Tags: android, json, android-sqlite

1. Create database with multiple tables.
2. Data should fetch from server as JSON format and insert into sqlite tables when app is installed.
3. ListViews should get populated with custom cursoradapter once JSON is fetching into sqlite. ListView has image, title, title description.
4. Json will get updated in the future, so i want to fetch the updated JSON objects(only) to sqlite rows and show in respective listviews.

Please suggest me the best possible way to do it. Thanks in advance.

My JSON format:

```
[{ 
    "Sermons Youtube ID" : "xxxxx",
    "Speaker" : "xxxxx",
    "node_title" : "xxxxxx",
    "Video_Length" : "xxxxx",
    "Image_Thumbnail" : "xxxx.png"
},
{
    "Sermons Youtube ID" : "xxxxx",
    "Speaker" : "xxxxx",
    "node_title" : "xxxxxx",
    "Video_Length" : "xxxxx",
    "Image_Thumbnail" : "xxxx.png"
},
{
    "Sermons Youtube ID" : "xxxxx",
    "Speaker" : "xxxxx",
    "node_title" : "xxxxxx",
    "Video_Length" : "xxxxx",
    "Image_Thumbnail" : "xxxx.png"
},
{
    "Sermons Youtube ID" : "xxxxx",
    "Speaker" : "xxxxx",
    "node_title" : "xxxxxx",
    "Video_Length" : "xxxxx",
    "Image_Thumbnail" : "xxxx.png"
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this example,
I hope it helps you,
JsonParsing and Sqlite Database
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e5156/jsonparsing-and-sqlite-database-in-android-using-android-stu/